# NLTK not working with CGI script

Tags: python, cgi, nltk

```
#![path_to_python_interpreter]
import sys
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print(sys.version)
```

The above code works perfectly on the web browser (localhost:8081/cgi-bin/script.py). However, when I add `import nltk`, it does not work, and gives an error: "End of script output before headers: script.py". However, nltk works perfectly for the python command line interpreter, and the python version names also match. So I assume the problem is definitely because of CGI. I am using 64-bit Windows 10. Here is my python version(32-bit):

> 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

Here are the Apache error logs when nltk is imported:

> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.813627 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] End of script output before headers: script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.813627 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] AH01215: Traceback (most recent call last):\r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.814125 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] AH01215:   File "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py", line 3, in \r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.814125 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] AH01215:     import nltk\r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.814628 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] AH01215:   File "C:\Users\slaYer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 160, in \r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.814628 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] AH01215:     from nltk.downloader import download, download_shell\r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.815124 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] AH01215:   File "C:\Users\slaYer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 2233, in \r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.815124 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] AH01215:     _downloader = Downloader()\r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.815124 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] AH01215:   File "C:\Users\slaYer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 437, in **init**\r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.815625 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] AH01215:     self._download_dir = self.default_download_dir()\r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.815625 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] AH01215:   File "C:\Users\slaYer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 946, in default_download_dir\r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.816127 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client 
>   ::1:57010] AH01215:     raise ValueError("Could not find a default download directory")\r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py
>
> [Fri Nov 03 10:58:07.816127 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 6796:tid 1844] [client ::1:57010] AH01215: ValueError: Could not find a default download directory\r: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/script.py